# Check if NSMutableArray has a specific Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying to check if the NSMutableArray has a specific object, before adding the object to it, if exists then don't add.

i looked over many posts explaining how to do this, managed to implement it like this, but it always gives me that the object "doesn't exist", though i already added it !

```
 //get row details into FieldLables Object
            AllItemsFieldNames *FieldLabels = feedItems[row];

            // object to hold single row detailes
            AllItemsFieldNames *SelectedRowDetails = [[AllItemsFieldNames alloc] init];
            SelectedRowDetails.item_name = FieldLabels.item_name;
            //SelectedRowDetails.item_img = FieldLabels.item_img;
            SelectedRowDetails.item_price = FieldLabels.item_price;

            //NSLog(@"item has been added %@", SelectedRowDetails.item_name);
            //NSLog(@"shopcartLength %lu", (unsigned long)SelectedFieldsNames.count);

            if([SelectedFieldsNames containsObject:SelectedRowDetails])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Already Exists!");
                }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Doesn't Exist!");
                [SelectedFieldsNames addObject:SelectedRowDetails];
            }
```

I can display all object from the NSMutableArray into a table, what i need to do in the above code is stop the addition of duplicate objects.

Comment: `containsObject` will work, **IF** you've properly defined the `isEqual` method for your class.  (Read the documentation!)

Comment: And if you override `-isEqual:` to implement what you consider equality for your class, you **have to** also implement `-hash` so that equal objects have the same hash.

Comment: Your logic is wrong.  SelectedRowDetails will always be a new object because of this line:  AllItemsFieldNames *SelectedRowDetails = [[AllItemsFieldNames alloc] init];

Comment: SelectedRowDetails is only used to temporarily hold the selected row data, just to add it to the NSMutableArray " SelectedFieldsNames " and then it will be reset to new object so as to hold the next row details... wrong ?

Comment: i think  you can avoid duplicates without specific object checking, directly add objects into NSMutableArray,after pass that NSMutableArray to NSMutableSet then set NSMutableSet  to NSMutableArray.

Comment: containsObject checks for object ID not the contents of the instance of that object.  So this line: if([SelectedFieldsNames containsObject:SelectedRowDetails]) will never become true.  I think what you wanted is to check for item_name ...

Comment: @user523234, no, `-containsObject:` checks object equality using `-isEqual:`. This is different from, for example, `-indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:`, which uses object identity.

Comment: @user523234 - **READ THE DOCUMENTATION!!**

Comment: ... I read, OP needed to override isEqual method in his custom class.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The first method listed on the NSArray documentation under the section "querying an array" is `containsObject:`. If it's not working, that suggests that your implementation of `isEqual:` is not correct. Make sure you follow the note in the documentation:

> If two objects are equal, they must have the same hash value. This
>   last point is particularly important if you define isEqual: in a
>   subclass and intend to put instances of that subclass into a
>   collection. Make sure you also define hash in your subclass.

You might also consider using an `NSSet` since you can't add duplicates to that. Of course, this would also require a working version of `isEqual:`.

Comment: `NSSet` may be worth considering as Stephen says, but in case it is not clear it too relies on `isEqual:` and so will fail if `containsObject:` does.

Comment: Perhaps a note on the equals contract? (ie it must be reflexive, symmetric, transitive and consistent) and on overriding hash?

Comment: Added both comments to the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure i get all this, could someone explain a bit more ? i should look into overriding hash and isEqual ?

Comment: You need to implement both hash and isEqual on the class you're adding to the array.

Answer (score -1):

Sets are composed of unique elements, so this serves as a convenient way to remove all duplicates in an array. 
here some sample,

```
NSMutableArray*array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", nil];
    [array addObject:@"4"]; 
    NSMutableSet*chk=[[NSMutableSet alloc ]initWithArray:array]; //finally initialize NSMutableArray   to NSMutableSet
    array= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[chk allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]]; //after assign NSMutableSet to your NSMutableArray and sort your array,because sets are unordered.
    NSLog(@"%@",array);//1,2,3,4
```

Comment: This does not constitute a suitable solution to the poster's problem. `NSSet` uses the same methods as `-[NSArray containsObject:]` to determine membership -- if the latter isn't working, then neither will `NSSet`.